Reciprocal lattice for non-bravais lattices
In crystallography, when dealing with a lattice that is not a Bravais lattice, from my understanding, we sometimes chose a bravais lattice and consider the "misbehaving" atoms as "motifs" of this lattice, for example in base centered cubics (we consider the basis atoms as motifs). However, how can we find the reciprocal lattices of such lattices ? I assume we cannot just use $\mathbf{a}_i \cdot \mathbf{b}_j = 2\pi \delta_{ij}$, since it would not take into account the motifs.
Thanks in advance for any help !

The reciprocal lattice does not consider the basis (your motifs).

I think you are just confused. Bravais lattices are meant to be used with basis; the resulting reciprocal lattice does not care about the basis being used. Instead, the Bloch wavefunctions will have symmetries that are affected by the basis. There is also no way to convert a Bravais lattice into another one that is incompatible e.g. there is no way to use a cubic lattice to cover a HCP structure. However, it is common to use simple cubic lattice to deal with BCC and FCC lattices, just because we are all lazy. The reciprocal lattices differ, but a mapping exists.

I guess I never used a simple cubic lattice to represent BCC or FCC since it just complicates things and hides relevant stuff. But I do remember that BCC and FCC are each the reciprocal lattice of the other.
